# Wordpress inserts <p></p> next to shortcode return value

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have created the following shortcode code:

```
<?php

function box_handle($atts, $content='')
{
    extract(
    shortcode_atts(array(
                        'size' => 'narrow'), $atts));
    return '<div class="box '.$size.'">'.$content.'</div>';
}

add_shortcode('box', 'box_handle');

?>
```

And this:

```
[box]<h2>Title</h2>
Content
Content
Content[/box]
```

Gives me

```
<div class="box narrow"><br>
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Impingement<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content</p></div>
<p></p>
```

The problem here being the extra `<br>` at the top, after the  opening tag. Keep reading and you will find a second error, the unwarranted `<p></p>`... How can I fix this? Naturally, I have gone through the HTML code in the admin panel and tried to weed out any new lines and other things around the markup which may cause this but I have not been able to fix it.

Comment: I now rewrote the html-code and the empty paragraph has been done away with. It was replaced by a <br>, which figure after both the ending and opening div tag.

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin, which should let you disable the wpautop()-function on a per-post-basis. I didn't tested that plugin yet.

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/wiki/TextControl

Comment: Per post basis won't quite cut it here. But thank you anyway, I might actually try to disable wpautop entirely.

Comment: which would be:
`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );`